# How should be stored sensitive Stripe key variable in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, security, stripe-payments

I use Stripe payment system in my Angular App. Is it secure to store key in code just like shown below or it should be done in another more secure way?

```
var handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_JsdSDASDsds2e213edwqsaP7',
  locale: 'auto',
```

Comment: Check out [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/keys) for stripe keys.

Comment: The Publishable Key (pk_) is not a secret key. It's not necessary to store it securely as it's visible to the client when being used.

Comment: Thank you for you responses, I store secret key in my Django API which download key from Google Secret Manager, so it looks as this is the most secure way and I can store `pk_key` in my Angular App as shown in the question, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should not store any sensitive keys in Angular. If it is in angular it is not stored secretly, it is publicly accessible. But the key you have isn't a secret key its a publishable key meaning it is meant for public access.

Your comment response above looks like you are doing the right thing.

Your Secret should always go in private api's (Make sure these keys are not published to public git repos hide them in .gitignore) Using Google Secret Manager is great!

If someone took your pk_key they would only be able to make requests that hit your endpoint with the secret key (very unlikely to happen). To prevent this you can enable cors on your apis blocking unwanted web requests.

As for how should your store keys I would recommend the environment.ts file, this is common practice for a few reasons. It is easy to heck, update, or delete keys. When setting up pipelines for different environments you won't be able to alter it easy without this method, and this makes local development easier.